# How to create variables that indicate start and end periods in a time series in R

Tags: r

I want to calculate when someone starts and stops commenting on a blog. My dataset has a userid in column 1, followed by 6 columns, each representing the number of comments in a time period. I'd like to create a column ('active') identifying the first period where a non-zero value appears. I'd also like to create a column ('inactive') that identifies the first period where a zero follows a non-zero value and is followed only by zeros in subsequent periods.

This is 10 rows of sample data:

```
structure(list(userid = c(199782L, 30982L, 27889L, 108358L, 29620L, 
229214L, 37531L, 711L, 30516L, 32360L), Period1 = c(0L, 1L, 43L, 
0L, 189L, 0L, 0L, 142L, 26L, 0L), Period2 = c(0L, 36L, 40L, 18L, 
32L, 0L, 6L, 55L, 159L, 0L), Period3 = c(0L, 68L, 25L, 110L, 
1L, 0L, 31L, 14L, 32L, 0L), Period4 = c(0L, 45L, 0L, 91L, 0L, 
0L, 54L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Period5 = c(93L, 27L, 57L, 0L, 0L, 35L, 
79L, 4L, 0L, 26L), Period6 = c(132L, 47L, 37L, 4L, 0L, 186L, 
50L, 2L, 0L, 191L)), .Names = c("userid", "Period1", "Period2", 
"Period3", "Period4", "Period5", "Period6"), row.names = 175:184, class = "data.frame")
```

Selected output for 5 of the rows follow. The absence of a value for 'inactive' means that the user is still active.:

```
userid, active, inactive
199782, 5
27889, 1
29620, 1, 3
37531, 2
30516, 1, 3
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to approach this? Thanks!

Comment: Your `active` column could be `apply(df[-1] > 0, 1, match, x = TRUE)` The other column will require more thought.  Do you care if the empty `inactive`s are `NA`? I would be better, I think.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Yes, inactives can be NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` for sugar syntax and to proceed by group of id ( after putting in the long format):

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(dat),id.vars='userid')[,
    list(active=min(which(value>0)),
         inactive={ mm = cumsum(value)
                    ## treat the case where we have leading 0 in value
                    mm = duplicated(mm[mm!=0])
               ## Note the use of integer here otheriwse data.table will complain about types...
                       ifelse(any(mm) && max(which(mm))==length(value),
                               min(which(mm)),NA_integer_)
         }),userid]

     userid active inactive
 1: 199782      5       NA
 2:  30982      1       NA
 3:  27889      1       NA
 4: 108358      2       NA
 5:  29620      1        4
 6: 229214      5       NA
 7:  37531      2       NA
 8:    711      1       NA
 9:  30516      1        4
10:  32360      5       NA
```

Explanation, for each id:

1. The active column is just the index of the first value not null
2. The inactive column is more tricky.It is the minimum index of the duplicated value in the cumulative sum of value. We should remove the null value from this cumulative sum to avoid the case where the value begin with zeros. Here a simple example:

   ```
    cumsum(c(1,0,1))  
   [1] 1 1 2
         _    ## we want to extract the index of one here
   min(which(duplicated(cumsum(c(1,0,1)))))
   2
   ```

Comment: Thanks. This correctly identifies 'active', but 'inactive' isn't working quite right. It seems to be flagging the first zero after a non-zero, but sometimes this is just a pause, and there is activity in subsequent periods. Example is userid 27889 which has activity in periods 1-3, nothing in period 4, and then resumes in periods 5-6.

Comment: @user3614783 well. Do you mean that once the user become inactive ,he cannot become active again?

Comment: @user3614783 I slightly modify the condition to to define inactivity period as the first non zero period followed only by zeros in subsequent periods.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. My definition of inactivity is the period after which there is never any more activity. If P1-P6 activity is 1,0,1,1,0,0, 'inactive'<>2 because activity resumes in P3. "inactive'=5 because after 5 there are only zeros.

Comment: @user3614783 in this case in your example , th expected output is : `30516, 1, 4` and not `30516, 1, 3`. Whatever, I think my last edit   give you the right answer.